# Atiyah-MacDonald Ex 2.10

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a ring. Let $\mathfrak a$ be an ideal contained int he Jacobson Radical of $A$. Let $u:M \rightarrow N$ be a morphism. Let $N$ be finitely generated. Show that if $w:M/\mathfrak a M \rightarrow  N/ \mathfrak a N$ is surjective then so is $u$.

Firstly this screams Nakayamma's lemma.
We have the following commutative diagram which we can apply the snake lemma to.
[image]
$\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$
If we suppose that $w$ is surjective then the $\coker(w)=0$. Then we have $\ker(w)\rightarrow \coker(v)\rightarrow \coker(u)\rightarrow 0$.

I'm not to sure what to do from here. The map $v$ is just the restriction of $u$ so there should be some nice between their cokernels but I cannot see what.

Comment: Hint: let $N’$ be the cokernel of $u$, which is finitely generated. Show $N’=\mathfrak{a}N’$...

Comment: If I show this Nakayama gives the result. I am a little confused on how to do so. I know that $N=coker(u)=im(coker(v)\rightarrow N)$. Now if $x$ is in $coker(v)$, we can lift $x$ to an $x'$ in $aN$. This $x'=an$ for some $n\in N$. This clearly includes into $N$. But I don't see what I can say for stuff in the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need exact sequences here. $N$ is finitely generated, $u(M)$ is its submodule, and it is easy to show that $N=\mathfrak{a}N+u(M)$. Now just apply corollary $2.7$ from Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: This is a very slick answer, I would still like to see how we can finish the approach I've taken

Comment: Actually its not clear to me why $N=\mathfrak a N+U(M)$.

Comment: Because given $n\in N$ there is some $m\in M$ such that $n+\mathfrak{a}N=w(m+\mathfrak{a}M)=u(m)+\mathfrak{a}N$. Then $n\in u(m)+\mathfrak{a}N\subseteq u(M)+\mathfrak{a}N$.

Comment: And if you want to solve it with cokernels, maybe you will find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855222/prove-that-if-the-induced-homomorphism-m-mathfrak-am-to-n-mathfrak-an-is-su?rq=1